# CSS3 search box responsive, Search button breaking up

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, search-box

I want to design a responsive search box for my website and so when I found this codepen fiddle - http://codepen.io/nikhil/pen/GuAho, I fiddled around with it and ended up with this version -
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qygrpe

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    /* CSS Search */

        .cf:before, .cf:after{
          content:"";
          display:table;
        }

        .cf:after{
          clear:both;
        }

        .cf{
          zoom:1;
        }

        /*-------------------------------------*/   

        .content-wrapper {
            width: 180px;
            padding: 0px;
            position:relative;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;

        }

    #search {
      position:relative;
      font-size:13px;font-family:"Dosis";
      float:right;
      margin-top:7px;
      right:5px;
    }
    #search-form {
      background-color:#314d5b;
      height:32px;
      line-height:32px;
      border:0 none;
      font-family:"Dosis";
      font-size:13px;
      font-weight:200;
      color:#b5c5ca;
      width:130px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
            border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;      
      box-shadow:inset 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      padding:0 10px;
      transition:all 0.5s ease 0s;
    }
    #search-form .search-button,#search-form .search-button:hover{
      transition:all 0.5s ease 0s;
      height:21px;
      width:21px;
      line-height:30px;
      background-color:#ed0b77;
      border:0 none;
      float:right;
      cursor:pointer;
      outline:none;
    }
    #search-form:hover{
      background-color:#f0f0f0;
    }
    #search-form:focus{
      background-color:#eee;
      text-shadow:none !important;
      outline:none;
      color:#459bb6;
    }
    #box {display:none}
    .search-text {
      font-size:13px;
      font-family:"Dosis";
      float:right;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    .search-text:hover {
      color:#459bb6
    }


        .content-wrapper button {
                overflow: visible;
            position: relative;
            float: right;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 32px;
            width: 30px;
            background: #416577;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
            border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
            text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
        }   

        .content-wrapper button:hover{      
            background: #e2614c;
        }   

        .content-wrapper button:active,
        .content-wrapper button:focus{   
            background: #c42f2f;    
        }

        .content-wrapper button:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
            border-style: solid solid solid none;
            border-color: transparent #416577 transparent;
            top: 8px;
            left: -5px;
        }

        .content-wrapper button:hover:before{
            border-right-color: #e2614c;
        }

        .content-wrapper button:focus:before{
            border-right-color: #c42f2f;
        }    

        .content-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }


<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div id='search'>
        <div class='content-wrapper cf'>
          <form action='/search' id='searchform' method='get'>
    <input id='search-form' name='q' onblur='if(this.value==&apos;&apos;)this.value=this.defaultValue;' onfocus='if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=&apos;&apos;' type='text' value='Looking for something?'/>
          <button class='search-button' title='Search' type='submit'><img alt='search button' src='http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-e8Tp2vSgy2c/VpS0vc8zi7I/AAAAAAAAAN0/6rDw0GIVaSg/s1600/mysearch2.png' title='Search'/>
    </button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I added the HTML code for the search box as well as its CSS to my blog's template and it's showing up nicely until the screen width is more than 600 pixels.
Have a look

[image]

But as soon as the width becomes 600 px or less, my search box is breaking up and isn't floating on the right, even though there is enough space. I even removed a few sections of my menu and left only "BLOGGER" and MUSIC" and still the search box is breaking out of the div.

[image]

Kindly point me where I am going wrong, I'm sure I am going the wrong direction somewhere in the CSS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://howaboutmyopinion.blogspot.in/ is where I have put it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this solution:

```
.content-wrapper {
    width: auto;
}
#search {
    position: absolute; // it was relative
}
div#menutop {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, much appreciated. However, it is still breaking up when the screen size gets lower than 600px. 
http://i.imgur.com/4l3450h.jpg

Comment: the search-form div (for the text input) seems to be floating on the left, though now after I made changes as suggested by you, the search button is more stable now, floating on the right.

Comment: just add div#search {
    width: auto !important;
} or just remove media querie  width:80% for `#search` and `#search-form` , working here http://i.imgur.com/HL8UsmO.png

Comment: Thank you so much, John, it worked :) Now the search box is not breaking up :) I had to remove the media querie width:x% for #search and #search-form everywhere and changed it to width: auto because even div#search { width: auto !important; } wasn't working.

Comment: However why is the question mark in the text "Looking for something?" inside the search-form getting partially clipped after screen-size gets less than 600 px? Is it because of width: auto ? http://i.imgur.com/o03Lhxs.jpg

Comment: your welcome, no it's because of width: auto, just check your code again if there is somehitng like @media screen and (max-width: 600px)
#search-form {
    font-size: 15px;
}

Comment: Oh, I really can't thank you enough, I searched and couldn't find #search-form { font-size: 15px; } in the media query and so added it and now it's showing up perfectly. Thank you so so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
transition:all 0.5s ease 0s;
  height:21px;
  width:21px;
  line-height:30px;
  background-color:#ed0b77;
  border:0 none;
  float:right;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
```

Try to give position:absolute

Comment: Thanks so much Black-smurf, but it is still breaking up.